# Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type text/plain

Tags: java, resteasy, jboss6.x

I have the application that runs on the JBoss 6.0.1.
I use REST architecture(RESTEasy) for invoke remote service and expect Json.I get exception when calling GET method.

**Here is exception message:** 
Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type text/plain;charset="utf-8"

**Here is my code:**

```
@Override
public Room getRoomEvents(String roomID, String date) throws BackEndException {

    Room room = null;
    try {
        ClientRequest.setDefaultExecutorClass("org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.executors.ApacheHttpClient4Executor", true);
        ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest(HOSTNAME + METHOD + ROOM_ID_ARG + roomID + DATE_ARG + date);
        request.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
        ClientResponse<Room> response = request.get(Room.class);
        if (response.getResponseStatus().getStatusCode() != 200) {
            throw new BackEndException(-110, Errors.ERROR_LOTUS_REQUEST, "Error lotus request");
        }
        room = response.getEntity();
        response.releaseConnection();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BackEndException(-109, Errors.ERROR_LOTUS_REQUEST, "Error lotus request");
    }
    return room;
}
```

In this line I get exception: **room = response.getEntity();**
Does anyone know what is mean and how to fix this exception?